# why session_start in php is throwing warning saying file large

Tags: php, session

I didn't change any code, all of a sudden when I visited one of the webpages, I see

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(..)Failed: File too large .. index.php on line 2.

Another error is:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent`

Line1 : `<?php`

Line2 : `session_start ();`

**Questions**:

1. what is the reason for error that tells File too large? what file is large?
2. why all-of a sudden there is an error without any file modification being done?
3. why it is throwing 'headers already sent', when there is nothing defined before `session_start`, not even a space ?
4. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** what is the reason for error that tells File too large? what file is large?

- This seems to be the hosting provider issue, as the original file was never modified, and the webpage has been tried from multiple browsers even after clearing the cache.
  When you do `session_save_path("../_session1001");` that is mentioned below, you can see that your session is written to that path, so may be that this file was becoming too large in your shared memory,and now that I explicitly mentioned a physical space to write the session files to, this error is no more.

**4.** How to fix this issue?

- Create a directory named say '_session1001' and give chmod 755 so your webserver (app) can write to it.
- Add this line before session_start
  `session_save_path("../_session1001");`
- Ensure you protect the directory via `.htaccess` file.

ie:
`<?php
session_save_path("../_session1001");
session_start();`

Read more here : http://php.net/session_save_path

Note:

Debian does not use the default garbage collector for sessions. Instead, it sets `session.gc_probability` to zero and it runs a cron job to clean up old session data in the default directory.

As a result, if your site sets a custom location with `session_save_path()` you also need to set a value for `session.gc_probability`,

e.g.:

`<?php
session_save_path('/home/example.com/sessions');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
?>`

Otherwise, old files in '/home/example.com/sessions' will never get removed!